# Can't link CSS and JavaScript to HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I am using flask to make a website, 
the HTML works fine' the website loads but for some reason, HTML and CSS just won't link:

I use the url_for Flask command but it is still isn't working, when I open the site and Inspect it, it looks like the link is working but the folders of css, javascript, etc... are empty

**HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>StoreScan</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="{{url_for('static', filename='style/assets/dollars.jpeg')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='style/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='style/style.css')}}">
    <script defer src="{{url_for('static', filename='app/app.js')}}"></script>
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>

<body>

<h1 class="display-1 text-center mt-4">
    <u>StoreScan</u>
</h1>

<div class="mt-5 row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="card bg-light" style="width: 22rem;">
        <div class="card-header">Authentication</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Welcome Back!</h5>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <button class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark">Login</button>
            <h6 class="mt-3">New here? </h6>
            <button class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-light ml-5" style="width: 22rem;">
        <div class="card-header">Search</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">What do you want to find?</h5>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <form class="form-inline" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                    <input class="form-control mr-2" name="content" id="content" type="text" placeholder="Your item.">
                    <button class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark">Search</button>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <input type="radio" name="options" value="ebay" id="option1" method="POST"> Ebay <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="options" value="amazon" id="option2" method="POST"> Amazon <br>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**DEBUGGER:**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:35:00] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:35:00] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:35:00] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:35:00] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:35:00] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:35:00] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:35:09] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:35:09] "GET /static/style/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:35:09] "GET /static/style/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:35:09] "GET /static/app/app.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:35:10] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:37:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:37:04] "GET /static/style/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:37:04] "GET /static/style/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:37:04] "GET /static/app/app.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:37:07] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:38:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:38:56] "GET /static/style/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:38:56] "GET /static/style/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:38:56] "GET /static/app/app.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:38:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:38:58] "GET /static/style/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:38:58] "GET /static/style/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Feb/2020 19:38:58] "GET /static/app/app.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask isn't finding your static folder. Where is it located? Unless you modified on your blueprint, flask will look for the satic folder on the same level of your main app.

So let's say you have your .py file that runs you app - flask_server.py on the example below - inside the first level of the "web" directory, flask will look for the static folder on the same level - the same is true for the templates folder:

[image]

Hope it suits you well. :)

Answer (score 0):

All Css and Js files are considered as Static files and are to be placed in a folder named **Static** by you in order for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge even though you're file directory is correct since your are using Jinja to you might wanna just use the file directory without the url_for function. So instead of {{url_for('static', filename='style/assets/dollars.jpeg')}}, just do 'style/assets/dollars.jpeg'. Hope this helps